# How is it possible for count distinct to show duplicates, but group by does not?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I want to query for duplicates in my data.

So, the first thing I do is I do a count distinct:

```
select count(distinct colA, colB ....) from Table
```

and a count:

```
select count(*) from Table
```

And I see that the count distinct is lower than the count(*).
So, now I want to actually see the duplicates, so I do this:

```
select colA, colB, .... count(*) from Table 
group by colA, colB ... having count(*) > 1;
```

Now, for some reason, this does not return any records at all.  The table is too big for me to show results here, and the columns too many.

How is it possible for both of these to be true?  the counts are different, but no rows show up when I group them and filter for `count(*) >1`?

Thanks.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you see may depend on the database you are using.  However, I'm pretty sure that the problem is due to `NULL` values in the columns.  For instance, MySQL explicitly describes `COUNT(DISTINCT)` as:

> `COUNT(DISTINCT expr,[expr...])`
>
> Returns a count of the number of rows with different non-NULL expr
>   values.

Not all databases support `COUNT(DISTINCT)` with multiple expressions.  Different databases may handle `NULL` values differently.  But, they seem to be the most likely cause of the discrepancy.

Comment: Thank you.  Same with `sparkSQL` which is what I'm using:  http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/cdh/5-1-x/Impala/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_count.html